# Why the variable is not defined?

Tags: javascript

Here invoke calcArea function, the function scope should be in the scope of the definition of it, but its scope has variables sideLength, why error?

```
var square = {
    sideLength: 6,
    calcArea: function () {
        console.log(sideLength * sideLength);
    }
};
square.calcArea();
```

Can you help me?

and

```
var square = {
    sideLength: 6,
    calcArea: function () {
        console.log(this.sideLength * this.sideLength);
    }
};
square.calcArea();
```

this is ok, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The variable `sideLength` doesn't exist. It is an attribute of the square object. That is why `this` is required to access it.

Comment: thx, but    in console.log(),     sideLength is not square.sdieLength?    I want to know why.thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three scopes in the example -- global scope (contains console), object scope (contains sideLength and calcArea), and function scope (empty).  sideLength is an object property, the variable sideLength is not defined in the function scope.  You can access object properties with the dot notation (square.sideLength === 6), and "sibling" properties from inside an object (ie, when running a method of the object) through the special object "this" (this.sideLength === 6).

Comment: To be precise, rather than saying "you can access 'sibling' properties from inside an object...", it would be more accurate to say "you can access 'sibling' properties from inside a **method on the object**".

Comment: get it.thank you.I have confused with function scope and object scope.:-)

Answer (score 1):

here:

```
var square = {
sideLength: 6,
calcArea: function () {
    console.log(sideLength * sideLength);
    }
}
```

`square.calcArea();` is a `member/method` which will be accessible by the `object only` that is why here it does not work where as in the `second one` it works because you are using `this` as the `current object` to access it.

```
var square = {
sideLength: 6,
calcArea: function () {
    console.log(this.sideLength * this.sideLength);
    }
}
square.calcArea();
 it works because you are using this.sideLength.
```

you can use `console.log(square.sideLength);` to see the value accessed by `square.sideLength=6`.

Comment: In the interest of accuracy, let's not call `calcArea` a "property id". To be precise, it should be called a "property", or a "member", or a "method". If you want to refer to the string "calcArea" acting as the key, it should be called "property name".

Comment: @torazaburo got you sir.